# Как сделать gitignore для файлов .idea и __pycache__*

Tags: python, github

Для выгрузки на GitHub необходимо убрать папки .idea и *pycache* ,однако добавив их в gitignore.txt это сделать не получается.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `pycache` и `__pycache__` это вообще-то разные вещи

Comment: Ну и файл должен называться не `gitignore.txt`, а `.gitignore`

Comment: А так же в начале нужно написать команду `git init`, а если нет гита то  установить [тут](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не балуйтесь, добавьте уже устоявшуюся готовую "болванку" ".gitignore для python"  например, [эту](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Python.gitignore)

Если же Вы хотите непременно написать .gitignore самостоятельно - то папки добавляются туда со слешом на конце, чтобы отличать их от файлов, например, `__pycache__/`

Кстати, оказывается, написать и опубликовать .gitignore на github - отличный способ получить офигенно "форкаемый" проект! Тот репозиторий, который я привел в начале ответа, форкнут более 75 тысяч раз!

Также, важное замечание, которое сделал andreymal и которое позволит не биться головой об клавиатуру: файл имеет имя `.gitignore`. То есть, не gitignore.txt и не gitignore. То, что он начинается с точки, делает его "скрытым". С точки зрения пользователей Windows - это файл без имени и с расширением gitignore

Comment: Заглушку прямо файлом в проект закинуть?

Comment: Да, просто добавить еще один файл в репозиторий... и не забудьте, что Вам писал Андрей в комментариях: gitignore - это файл без расширения! не gitignore.txt!

Comment: @S.H. это файл с именем «» и расширением `.gitignore` :)

Comment: @andreymal - Прошу прощения, "зевнул", как говорят шахмастисты :-) Я исправлю этот момент в ответе.